# ng-include dont work on ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple angular app but the template is growing. I want to split it and use the `ng-include` directive but I can't get it to include correctly.

#### current `template.html`

```
<div class="edit-object-form" ng-show="editable">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
<div class="list-objects" ng-show="!editable">
    <!-- ... -->
</div
```

#### desired `template.html`

```
<div class="edit-object-form" ng-show="editable">
    <div ng-include="/partials/edit_objet_form.html"></div
</div>
<div class="list-objects" ng-show="!editable">
    <!-- ... -->
</div
```

The default value of `editable` is `false`, but when I switch to `true` the include directive doesn't work.

Note: I'm using Angular-1.0.7

Comment: Try put the url in quotes like this `<div ng-include="'/partials/edit_objet_form.html'">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to recreate this issue. Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hl4QyCz31r45AecqUyEM?p=preview) that loads two different templates. (The both look odd, since they're templates stolen from other plunkers to allow for xss).

Maybe this issue is caused by the two incomplete div ending tags, that are .

Comment: i dont know why but putting into quotes like @sza comment make it works

Comment: It works because `ng-include src` expects an expression that evaluates to an URL. If you want to pass in a constant string, you need to wrap it in quotes.